# Save name instead of ID from Rails Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, department and staff, as shown below:

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord

end

class Staff < ApplicationRecord

end
```

When creating a new staff, I have a dropdown listing the various departments.

```
<%= form.collection_select :department, Department.order(:name),:name,:name, 
include_blank: true %>
```

In my staff table, instead of having the `department_id` column, I have `department` instead. I am trying to save the department name instead of department_id when I select from the dropdown. From my dropdown above, I am still saving IDs and that's not what I want.

Is it possible to save the name instead of the department_id?

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like a bad practice. With your given informations you don't need a `Department` table.

If your are just looking to save department as a `string` I suggest you to render a collection from a `constant` for example.

Inside your model `Staff`

```
DEPARTMENTS = ['HR', 'IT', 'OFFICE']
```

and in your view

```
f.input :department, collection: DEPARTMENTS
```

I hope it could help.

Comment: Thank you for your great feedback. I have mainly chosen to go down this road to make it easy to import CSV by users. If I use constants, can I use dynamic select dropdowns?

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to achieve by using dynamic select dropdowns, but on paper it should works.